# Is there a faster way than fscanf while reading a large data

Tags: c, optimization, file-io

I am struggling with large mass structured data. I have a file which contains name and door numbers. I am using fscanf to read name and that numbers then I am storing them in smaller files using fprintf.

```
while ( fscanf(file, "%s %d", &people[i].name, &people[i].doorNum) > 0 ) {      
      ...
}
```

people is a struct array

```
typedef struct {                                        
   char* name;
   int doorNum;
}person;
```

The file I'm trying to read is 15 GB. My goal is reading them and splitting into 1GB files. It perfectly works but it takes more than 10 minutes. How can I improve these reading and writing data processes?

Comment: If you're just trying to split, can you reliably find a point where you can split if you just jump in mid-stream?  If so, binary copy without parsing up to 1023MiB, then copy-while-parsing until you find a split point.  If the structure is simple, like each line is a record, then you can use the `split` shell command.  Or do you need to parse string->int and then print int->string for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All files contain binary data. Some formats are efficient, and some aren't.

For example; to store the number 0x1234 you could store it as the 2-byte sequence `0x34, 0x12` so that it can be reconstructed with a small number of simple/fast operations (e.g. `value = buffer[pos] | (buffer[pos+1] << 8);`). This would be relatively efficient.

Alternatively; you could store it as the 5-byte sequence `0x34, 0x36, 0x36, 0x40, 0x00` where each byte represents an ASCII character in a string (with a zero terminator at the end); then you could scan the bytes and convert them from decimal to integer using an expensive loop like this:

```
    while( (c = buffer[pos++]) != 0) {
        if( (c < '0') || (c > '9') ) {
             // Error condition(!)
        }
        value = value * 10 + c - '0';
     }
```

Then you could make it worse by wrapping it in "convenience" (e.g. `fscanf()`) where the code has to scan a format string just to figure out that it needs to do something like that expensive loop.

Basically; if you care about performance and/or efficiency (including file size) you need to stop using "plain text" and design a file format to suit the data; especially when you're looking at huge 15 GB files.

**EDIT: Added everything below!**

If you're stuck with "plain text", then you can get a little more performance by doing more of the parsing yourself (e.g. using functions like `atoi()`, etc). The next step beyond that is to use your own (more specialised) routines instead of functions like `atoi()`.

The next step beyond that is to use a deterministic finite state machine. The general idea might go something like:

```
    switch( state | buffer[pos++] ) {
        case START_OF_LINE | 'A':
        case START_OF_LINE | 'B':
        case START_OF_LINE | 'C':
            string_start = pos - 1;
            string_length = 1;
            state = GETTING_NAME;
            break;
        case GETTING_NAME | 'A':
        case GETTING_NAME | 'B':
        case GETTING_NAME | 'C':
            string_length++;
            break;
        case GETTING_NAME | ' ':
            number = 0;
            state = GETTING_NUMBER;
            break;
        case GETTING_NUMBER | '0':
            number = number * 10;
            break;
        case GETTING_NUMBER | '1':
            number = number * 10 + 1;
            break;
        case GETTING_NUMBER | '2':
            number = number * 10 + 2;
            break;
        case GETTING_NUMBER | '\n':
            create_structure(string, string_length, number);
            line++;
            state = START_OF_LINE;
            break;
        default:
            // Invalid character
            printf("Parse error at line %u!\n", line);
            break;
    }
```

Hopefully the compiler takes that huge `switch()` that you end up with and optimises it into a fast jump table. Of course constructing something like this by hand is painful and error prone; and you'd probably be able to find a "parser generator" that does it for you (based on rules).

The next step beyond that is multi-threading. For example, you can have a thread that scans through the file searching for `'\n'` characters, and when it finds one it hands the line off to a worker thread (where the worker thread can use any of the methods above to parse the line). In that way you can have multiple CPUs all parsing in parallel.

In addition to all of that; you want to be loading data from disk while you're parsing the data. For example; while you're processing the first MiB of data you want to be loading the second MiB of data in parallel; and you don't want to load 1 MiB then parse 1 MiB, then load the next MiB then parse the next MiB, etc. To do this you need to use something like (e.g.) POSIX asynchronous IO functions; or alternatively (on a 64-bit OS that supports pre-fetching) memory mapped files.

Comment: I learned a lot thing. I mean this is so clean, but it is hard to implement for me. fscanf is very easy to use. But it is always checking the data which will be scanned. The problem is I am stuck in that "plain text" and I need a more efficient and easy to use way that can be alternative to fscanf.

Comment: @AlwaysNewbie: Added more to the answer to cover plain text :-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't tell us what you mean by "splitting".

It could be that reading the fields as a string of characters and an integer is useless (maybe a single string or two separate strings are enough).

Write your own scanning function with built-in knowledge of the pattern to be matched, this will certainly be more efficient. Even writing you own conversion to integer should be better.

Comment: Could you give me an example for a custom scanning function ? A link can also be beneficial.

Comment: Hem, is `while (input[i++] != ' ');` so difficult to think of ?

Comment: You mean, loop until to see '  ' character, and this is the name of the person. Then go until to see "\n" character and this is your doorNumber. Do you mean something like that ?

Comment: @AlwaysNewbie: you get it.

Comment: Okay so I will use fgets then I will parse the data according to my needs. I am trying now.

Answer (score 0):

`fscanf()` has a lot of feature which are not likely to be used at the same time, which make it slower. I suggest that you code your own function using `fread()`. As your function will have only one specific tasks it should be faster.

Comment: Could you give me some examples or useful links for fread() ?

Comment: fread is specified as; `size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);` so it needs how much elements it will read at one time. The problem is that I don't know the number of the elements in a line. I mean one line could be 20 the other could be 25. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You're right, you can either code a function that will concatenate a few segments of line to get a full line or use `fgets()` which is at higher level.